# Fancybox 2 Wont Close After Form Submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, fancybox-2

Currently I have a Form in Fancybox 2 that is submitted to a page that processes changes. Once the processing page is loaded into Fancybox it fails to close. It simply freezes on the screen.

I was able to bind it to the submit with a simple on click however the form validations perform with an alert that something is missing (yes it's missing for testing the validations) once you click OK on the Alert it continues to close. So either another concept needs to be used or a way to make sure that the form validation is true before performing the close function.

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Make Changes" onClick="parent.$.fancybox.close();" />
```

The Validation is simple JavaScript function called form_validator(form1) which must be "return(true);" of course. So is there a way to perform a IF on the onClick functions like

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Make Changes" onClick="IF (form_validator(form1)==return(true)) {parent.$.fancybox.close};" />'
```

Solved.. Placing the parent.$.fancybox.close(); inside the validator before the return(true); solved the problem and closes the window as intended without inline script.

Comment: For a good starter, don't use inline script to bind event

Comment: Well I've tried to find a way to make the Fancybox close on the processing page however all attempts have failed so the inline actually submitted the data and was processed while closing the fancybox successfully but not keeping the Fancybox open if the form failed validation. Still no solution...